# Connecting MySql With Entity Framework c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mysql-connector

I have a stable program working with local SQL Server, However the client requires online access (with low budget) to the database. So I decided to migrate to MySQL (if you have any suggestion with that)

Now, When I try to create Entity Framework with the MySql server I get this error
[image]

I tried couple of things but none of them worked for me. I'm new to MySql

Comment: Have you clicked the ‘learn more about this’ link?

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that. I clicked and read, sadly didn't help me

Comment: You have tagged: 'mysql-connector' ! Have you installed that?

Comment: I was in a similar situation where SQL Server licensing costs was a pretty big barrier and the clients needed an alternative. I was considering MySQL and ended up instead using PostgreSQL/NpgSql, as the tooling and EF support looked to be more comparable and compatible with schemas & such created against SQL Server. There were some small hurdles with things like default naming convention and some data types (I.e. GUIDs) but overall it transitioned rather smoothly. It might be worth a look if you haven't considered that DB/provider yet.

Comment: @StevePy Py I will check that. Thank you for sharing I appreciate it

Comment: @PoulBak sure I did sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling, here how I solved it.

First, go to  Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet package ...

Go to "Installed" tab  and uninstall all what you have there (In my case was a new project to test connection, so nothing was important there)

Go to "Browse" tab and search and install the following:

```
* EntityFramework by Microsoft 
* MySql.Data by Oracle 
* MySql.Data.EntityFramework by Oracle
```

Clean and build solution then add your Entity framework